# Subspace of metric space and neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $F\subset E$. If $x\in F$, in order
> that $W\subset F$ be a neighborhood of $x$ in $F$, a necessary and
> sufficient condition is that $W=V\cap F$, where $V$ is a neighborhood
> of $x$ in E.

Let $W\subset F$ be a neighborhood of $x\in E$ in $F$. By definition of neighborhood, there exists an open subset $U$ of $F$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subset W$. Also, there exists an open subset $A$ of $E$ such that $U=A\cap F$. But, how do I find a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $E$ such that $W=V\cap F$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $W = V \cap F$, where $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $E$.

This means that $\exists V^* \subseteq E$ such that $V^*$ is open and $x \in V^* \subseteq V$. So we know that $V^* \cap F \subseteq \underbrace{V\cap F}_W$. This means that $V^* \cap F \subseteq W$.

Now, we know that $x \in V^* \cap F$, so we have that $x \in V^* \cap F \subseteq W$ **(1)**.

Because $V^* \cap F$ is open in $F$, this means that $W$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $F$.